# Bootstrap bigger elements

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, smarty

I'm having to dynamically generate text. The text is 2 - 3 lines long. However when putting it in an element with bootstrap it sometimes makes the element to big if it has 3 lines. Is there anyway I can automatically set the size for 3 lines so all elements will be the same size?

I am using smarty template system.

```
<div class="row row-eq-height">
    {foreach item=inventoryItem from=$inventory}
        <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
            {foreach key=key item=item from=$inventoryItem}
                {if $key == "icon_url"}
                    <img src="http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/{$item}"  width="128" height="96">
                {/if}
                <div class="caption">
                {if $key == "name"}
                    <h3><center>{$item}</center></h3>
                {/if}
                {if $key == "price"}
                    <p><center>${$item}</center></p>
                {/if}
                </div>
            {/foreach}
            </div>
        </div>
    {/foreach}

</div>
```

Comment: What is your code and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried 'row-eq-height' but it didn't seem to help at all. I've read I might need to use javascript but I don't really want to do that and thought there must be a way to do it by HTML/CSS...

Comment: please include the HTML/CSS you've written so far.

Comment: Added, I am using Smarty.

Comment: Can you provide the source code instead of your smarty code? It would be helpful to see what the output is. Or if you can duplicate your problem in a [js.fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) that works too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `min-height` for `<div class="col-sm-1 col-md-3">`

If you use `row-eq-height` you have to add it to your css file. See [this example](http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/).